# Creating command in sublime text 3 (RegReplace)

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm relatively new to sublime 3. I'm trying to use the RegReplace package to create custom regex find and replace commands that I can run from the command palate. I managed to create the custom rules, but don't know how to execute them.

The RegReplace website states: "Once you have replacements defined, there are a number of ways you can run a sequence. One way is to create a command in the command palette by editing/creating a Default.sublime-commands in your User folder and then adding your command(s)"

I edited the file that appeared when I clicked "Preferences: Reg Replace - User" on the command palate, adding the code below:

```
{
    "caption": "Reg Replace: process evernote",
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {"replacements": ["remove evernote bullets", "last option removal"], "find_only":false}
}
```

However, this command does not appear on my command palate. How do I execute a predefined find and replace rule in RegReplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that you get to when you select `Preferences > Reg Replace > User` is a settings file that stores settings specific to `RegReplace`.

As the referenced help page mentioned, you need to create a file named `Default.sublime-commands` inside of your `User` package (use `Preferences > Browse Packages` to see where that is if you're not sure) (or open it if it already exists) and then add in your code from above.

A `sublime-commands` file is a JSON file that expects an array of the commands to be added to the command palette, so you'll need to make sure that you wrap the above in `[` and `]` to turn it into an array:

```json
[
    {
        "caption": "Reg Replace: process evernote",
        "command": "reg_replace",
        "args": {"replacements": ["remove evernote bullets", "last option removal"], "find_only":false}
    }
]
```

Comment: The file I edited was actually the same as the one I found using "Browse Packages" (a default.sublime-commands file). I think RegReplace added a link to the command palate so users would find it easier to edit it. Once I made it an array it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: making sure it's an array did the trick. thank you for this